# Need help to understand where bitcoin transaction has gone

Tags: bitcoind, blockchain, bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cli, listtransactions

I am new with bitcoin and I need some help from experienced members.

I have a server with bitcoin core where we accept some payments and use bitcoin core as mercant.

The problem is that we have got an incoming transaction which we didn't see in our wallet.

Here is the hash of the transaction: `460c0dc70ef52fd66142d1798a1735b4613c9ffec478efe5997d1ede0d16f28a`

In our bitcoin core through the bitcoin-cli command line I can see the following:

```
bitcoin-cli listtransactions 1K7Pci1re92vQuTSXbirmvQsmYMpXHQWbQ
[
  {
    "account": "1K7Pci1re92vQuTSXbirmvQsmYMpXHQWbQ",
    "address": "1K7Pci1re92vQuTSXbirmvQsmYMpXHQWbQ",
    "category": "receive",
    "amount": 7.02278014,
    "label": "1K7Pci1re92vQuTSXbirmvQsmYMpXHQWbQ",
    "vout": 1,
    "confirmations": 128,
    "blockhash": "000000000000000002ef00cf04d1a6197cd07d5b7826d2dc8cd8a86fd41d578f",
    "blockindex": 425,
    "blocktime": 1463303078,
    "txid": "460c0dc70ef52fd66142d1798a1735b4613c9ffec478efe5997d1ede0d16f28a",
    "walletconflicts": [
    ],
    "time": 1463299775,
    "timereceived": 1463299775,
    "bip125-replaceable": "no"
  }, 
  {
    "account": "1K7Pci1re92vQuTSXbirmvQsmYMpXHQWbQ",
    "category": "move",
    "time": 1463303102,
    "amount": -0.00007000,
    "otheraccount": "1M1LTHjc1JAcVfCoyhSkoP1VH8B9RLY8tg",
    "comment": "merchant fee"
  }, 
  {
    "account": "1K7Pci1re92vQuTSXbirmvQsmYMpXHQWbQ",
    "category": "move",
    "time": 1463303102,
    "amount": -7.02278014,
    "otheraccount": "1LBa3bAVF5RSfnFnm3sX1Zm5R8WU1J8xnK",
    "comment": "invoice forward"
  }
]
```

As I see funds were successfully moved to `1LBa3bAVF5RSfnFnm3sX1Zm5R8WU1J8xnK`, which is correct, but on blockchain, for example, if I go here 
https://blockchain.info/address/1K7Pci1re92vQuTSXbirmvQsmYMpXHQWbQ 
I see that were sent to another address!

How to understand that, and how to find where these bitcoins have gone?

Any help will be appreciated, thank you very much!

Comment: And the main problem that there is no money on my wallet...

Comment: Did the private key of `1LBa3bAVF5RSfnFnm3sX1Zm5R8WU1J8xnK` begins with 5 ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the address you provided is really your address and not just watch only one there are basically two possibilities:

1. You have sent the money to another address and forgotten about that (or misunderstood what you are doing),
2. Your wallet got compromised either by giving private key to some malicious third part or via computer virus which stolen it without your knowledge.

In either way the address you mentioned is now empty and you cannot take the money back unless you control the addresses it is now on.